# Understand online payments through Braintree in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I am building an application which will require to accept online payments from users. The library that I am trying to implement is Braintree Gateway.

Instead of just solving my issue I have I prefer to understand how exactly does Braintree handle the money transfer. If someone could recommend a source where I could learn this or explain it to me that would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.sitepoint.com/integrate-braintree-payments-rails/) might be helpful.

It has a whole section on how braintree works.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with that page. It explains quite well how to set up online payments on Ruby (and other languages too), but it does not explain what are the actions that Ruby has to do during this process.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

Looking at our [getting started guide](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/get-started/overview) will give you a nice overview of how payments work from a non-technical perspective.

If you are looking for a more technical perspective of how things work, you should visit our [developer page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) and read the source code of our [client library](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ruby).